# Automatically create Woocommerce SKU with save_post hook

Tags: woocommerce, save, hook, custom-taxonomy, sku

I need to create a unique SKU that is made up of 3 custom taxonomies any time a new product is saved, but having trouble getting at the custom taxonomies. This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_sku', 10,3 );

function set_sku( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( $update ){
        return;
    }

    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'product' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
    $producer = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'producer') );
    $vintage = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'vintage') );
    $bottle_size = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'bottle_size') );
    $your_sku = $producer . "|" . $vintage . "|" . $bottle_size;

    if( empty( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true ) ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $your_sku );
    }


}
```

This resulting SKU when a new product is created is this:

```
||
```

PS there is only ever one value assigned to each custom taxonomy.

Any help appreciated. I am using a similar function on the front end that is correctly displaying the data, a sample of which is here:

```
<?php 

    $products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,

    ) );


    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); $id = $product->get_id();?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $producer = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $id, 'producer') ); ?</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to loop through the products using wc_get_products inside the function. Seems like a waste of resources and was hoping to just use the current post ID, but it works and WP is built on loops after all. Tested and working, and a cool way to both automate and control SKU creation.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_sku', 10,3 );

function set_sku( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( $update ){
        return;
    }

    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'product' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }



    $args = array(
            'limit' => 9999999,
            'orderby'  => 'name',
        );

        $productData = wc_get_products( $args );

        foreach ( $productData as $product ){

            $productId = $product->get_id();
            $producer = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $productId, 'producer') );
            $vintage = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $productId, 'vintage') );
            $bottle_size = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $productId, 'bottle_size') );
            $your_sku = $producer . "|" . $vintage . "|" . $bottle_size;

            if( empty( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true ) ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $your_sku );
            }
        }


}
```